# How to convert HEXEWKB to Latitude, Longitude (in python)?

Tags: python, gis, openstreetmap, latitude-longitude

I downloaded some Point of Interest data from OpenStreetMap and as it turn outs the locations are encoded in HEXEWKB format:

```
CSV fields
==============================================
1 : Node type;  N|W|R (in upper case), wheter it is a Node, Way or Relation in the openstreetmap model
2 : id; The openstreetmap id
3 : name;   The default name of the city
4 : countrycode;    The iso3166-2 country code (2 letters)
5 : alternatenames; the names of the POI in other languages
6 : location;   The middle location of the POI in HEXEWKB
7 : tags; the POI tags : amenity,aeroway,building,craft,historic,leisure,man_made,office,railway,tourism,shop,sport,landuse,highway separated by '___'
```

I need to transform these into longitude/latitude values. This very same question was asked before for the Java language ([How to convert HEXEWKB to Latitude, Longitude (in java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346113/how-to-convert-hexewkb-to-latitude-longitude-in-java)), however I need a Python solution.

My attempts so far have been focused in trying to use GeoDjango's GEOS module (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#creating-a-geometry), but since I'm not using Django in my application this feels a bit like an overshooting. Is there any simpler approach?

Comment: A quick intro to the spec https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Well-known_binary includes a link to PyGeoIf https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygeoif

Comment: Hugh, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it seems that pygeoif can only process locations in Well-known Text format, while my data seems to be in HEXadecimal Extended Well-Known Binary (HEXEWKB).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After trying different libraries I found the most practical solution in a somewhat related question: [Why can shapely/geos parse this 'invalid' Well Known Binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500460/why-can-shapely-geos-parse-this-invalid-well-known-binary). This involves using **shapely** (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely):

```
from shapely import wkb
hexlocation = "0101000020E6100000CB752BC86AC8ED3FF232E58BDA7E4440"
point = wkb.loads(hexlocation, hex=True)
longitude = point.x
latitude = point.y
```

That is, you just need to use **wkb.loads** to transform the HEXEWKB string to a shapely Point object, then extract the long/lat coordinates from that point.